# I need help with this exercise on limits at infinity.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

The exercise I propose is the following.

Let $a_0, a_1, ...., a_p$ be real numbers whose sum is equal to zero.

Justify that

$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (a_0\sqrt{n}+a_1\sqrt{n+1}+a_2\sqrt{n+2}+...+a_p\sqrt{n+p}) = 0$

I tried to get a common factor $\sqrt{n}$ and then try to group the terms together $a_0, a_1, a_p$ to add them.
However, I can't come up with anything concrete to give me an idea of the limit.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $a_p=-a_1-a_2-\cdots-a_{p-1}$ and therefore your limit is the sum of the limits\begin{multline}\lim_{n\to\infty}a_0\sqrt{n}-a_0\sqrt{n+p},\lim_{n\to\infty}a_1\sqrt{n+1}-a_1\sqrt{n+p},\ldots\\\ldots,\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{p-1}\sqrt{n+p-1}-a_{p-1}\sqrt{n+p}\end{multline}(if all of them exist). And it's not hard to prove that each of them is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** I think that your idea is almost right, just that you shouldn't consider $\sqrt{n}$ as a factor you have to pull out, but as a summand:
Observe that for a given $n$, we have

$$
a_0 \sqrt{n} + a_1 \sqrt{n+1} + \dots + a_p \sqrt{n+p}
= \sum_{i=0}^{p} a_i \sqrt{n} + \sum_{i=0}^{p} a_i (\sqrt{n+i} - \sqrt{n})
$$

Can you show that this converges to $0$?